# Change of the limits of integration

Tags: calculus

I want to change the following parametric equation to cylindrical coordinates:
$$x=x \\y=y\\ z=4-x^2-y^2\\$$
The limits of integration are :
$$0 \leq x \leq 1 \\ 0 \leq y \leq 1$$
In cylindrical coordinates:
$$x=r\cos\theta\\y=r \sin\theta\\z=4-r^2$$
To change the limits of integration I proceed like that?:
$$x=0 \\ y=0 \\z=4-0^2-0^2=4\\4=4-r^2\\r=0 $$
$$x=1 \\ y=1 \\z=4-1^2-1^2=2\\2=4-r^2\\r=\sqrt{2}  $$
Therefore:
$$r ~ \in~ [0,\sqrt {  2}  ]$$
Analogously for $\theta$:
$$x=0 \\ y=0 \\ 0=(0)\cos\theta \quad 0=(0)\sin\theta\\ \theta=0 $$
$$x=1 \\ y=1 \\ 1=\sqrt2\cos\theta \quad 1=\sqrt{2}\sin\theta\\ \theta=\frac { \pi  }{  4}  $$
Therefore:
$$r ~ \in~ \left[0,\sqrt {  2}  \right]\\\theta ~ \in~ \left[0,\frac { \pi  }{  4}   \right]$$

Answer (score 0):

It's awkward to integrate over a square in polar coordinates. You have to split it into two integrals, one with $0\le \theta\le \pi/4$, the other with $\pi/4\le\theta\le\pi/2$. In your case, the integrals over those two triangles will be equal, and so you can just do one of them and double your answer. Draw a picture: When $0\le\theta\le\pi/4$, $r$ starts at $0$ and goes up to $r=1/\cos\theta$. Why?